# Convert a mysql query to work with postgresql too

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I have a query which works well under mysql, i need to convert this query to work too unser which is the following :

```
SELECT u.*,
    ju.username,
    ju.email,
    ju.lastvisitDate as last_login,  
    team_leader.first_name  as leader_first_name,team_leader.last_name as leader_last_name, 
    team.leader_id as leader_id, 
    IF(team.name!='',team.name,team_leader.first_name || ' ' || team_leader.last_name) AS team_name 
FROM bpfsz_users AS u 
LEFT JOIN bpfsz_users AS ju ON ju.id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN bpfsz_teams AS team ON team.team_id = u.team_id 
LEFT JOIN bpfsz_users AS team_leader ON team_leader.id = team.leader_id
```

The query fails under postgreSQL with the error message "the function if(boolean, character varying, text) doesn't exist"

How to make working this query both in mysql and postgresql ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 2):

Postgresql is case sensitive.

You wrote: "in the table definition of bpfsz_users the column is nammed lastvisitDate"

So you must reference the column as: ju."lastvisitDate"

Just check cases.

The if must be converted to this:

```
CASE team.name
    WHEN '' THEN team_leader.first_name || ' ' || team_leader.last_name
    ELSE team.name
END AS team_name
```

Comment: In the table definition the column is nammed lastvisitDate and my query the column is wrote : ju.lastvisitDate

Comment: Quote it: ju."lastvisitDate"

Comment: I have re-tried with the query in my message above and it fails now on the if and it said nothing on the ju.lastvisitDate

Comment: Sorry, i focused on the error. The if must be converted to a postgresql equivalent. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks i tried with your example and my query works now

Answer (score 0):

> The query fails under postgreSQL with the error message "the column ju.lastvisitdate doesn't exist", in the table definition of bpfsz_users the column is nammed lastvisitDate

PostgreSQL folds unquoted identifiers to lowercase. As far as PostgreSQL is concerned, all these are identical.

```
select current_date;
select Current_Date;
select CURRENT_DATE;
```

The easiest fix is probably to rename the column to "last_visit_date", and use that in all your queries.  All lowercase with underscores to separate words is more consistent with the style of your other identifiers, and it avoids your problem.

To get PostgreSQL to respect your capitalization, enclose identifiers in double quotes.

```
select "ju"."lastvisitDate"
```

But that will break MySQL, which by default will use backticks to quote identifiers. IIRC, there's a MySQL server configuration setting to make it use double quotes instead, but that's more likely to break a lot of MySQL code than renaming the column.

---

[MySQL ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) makes the MySQL server parse text between backticks *and* between double quotes as identifiers. That means you can't use double quotes to identify literal strings.

Comment: If i put u.lastvisitDate in the query the query works but with ju.lastvisitDate the query doesn't work. I don't think that the LEFT JOIN bpfsz_users AS ju ON ju.id = u.id is really necessary here in the query.

Comment: The join might not be necessary, but what you wrote still doesn't make sense. The aliases "u" and "ju" refer to the same table.  PostgreSQL still folds unquoted identifiers to lowercase.

Comment: I have tried a new time without modifying the query, but now it fails on the IF with the error : the function if(boolean, character varying, text) doesn't exist

Comment: Use a `CASE` construct instead of IF. CASE is standard, IF is not standard.